# I don't understand what I'm doing wrong with my de-allocation of memory

Tags: c++, list, memory, linked-list, delete-operator

So I have a linked list getting created correctly, linked properly but when I try to de-allocate memory I can't seem to delete any node, the list still exists.
Code for my list deconstructor:

```
void LL_User::free_memory() {
    // TODO
    LL_User_Node *currentNode;
    currentNode = head;
    while(currentNode) {
        LL_User_Node *temp = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    //cout << "LL_User::free_memory() is not implemented yet.\n";
}

LL_User::~LL_User() {
    if(head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    free_memory();
}
```

And my user class has this for the vars and deconstructor:

```
User::User() {
    username = "";
    password = "";
    first_name = "";
    last_name = "";
    profile_pic_filename = "";
    birth_year = 0;
    birth_month = 0;
    birth_day = 0;
}

User::~User() {
    //Nothing placed in body because strings and ints are dealt with by OS?
}
```

Comment: why do you `new` variables in your `free_memory` function?!

Comment: `currentNode = head;` creates a memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code as written now only has one serious flaw; you delete the list chained to `head`, but never set head to `NULL`. Anyone touching it from this point on is hitting undefined behavior through a garbage pointer.

Set head to NULL if you're wiping the list like this. Alternatively, since you know `head` should be `NULL` after this is done anyway, forego using `currentNode` at all. Simply use `head` itself as the pointer that is walking the list. Think about that for awhile and it will come to you.

Also, as-written the check for (`head == NULL`) is not needed in your destructor. It is already checked in your `free_memory()` function, as it should be.

Comment: sorry, removed that part, that was for testing to see if items were getting deleted

Comment: I have no runtime errors, it's a logic error I'm assuming, because if I try to access the list after I run the free memory function, the list still exists and all data is locatable

Answer (score -1):

You're manually deallocating it, that's what you're doing wrong. Use a smart pointer like a wise man, have a program that works like a man who wants to get paid for his craft.

Comment: I concur on the smart pointer, particularly if the OP was asked, and verified, he was using a C++11 compliant toolchain. I see no mention of usages (or desire therein) of boost, though the inclusion of boost smart pointers is such a no-brainer I can' see why he wouldn't use them.

Comment: He tagged C++- that's C++11 as of some time in 2011. Even `auto_ptr` would work fine in this situation.

Comment: It is? then when is the impending deprecation of the C++11 tag?

Comment: No, i meant I've seen no announcement of it. For *months* I watched after the announcement (and even now) that the `homework` tag was deprecated and to stop using it. I've seen no such announcement whatsoever about C++ 11, and in fact this is the very first I've heard of such a thing.

Comment: Probably because the intricacies of the C++ tags are left to the C++ community. And in both C++11 and C++03, the only sane advice to "How do I delete something?" is "Use a smart pointer."

Comment: @WhozCraig, no, the C++11 tag is not deprecated. That's irrelevant though. Smart pointers are technology from the previous millenium.

Comment: Whilst smart pointers are a better solution then manual memory management, this is clearly a technical exercise, else the OP should just use a Linked List from the the standard library. As such you have failed to explain to the OP what is actually wrong with the code in question and failed to provide any coherent way of improving it. What you have done is akin to walking into the Somme and proclaimed "Don't get shot", whilst reasonable advice, it is both painfully obvious and utterly useless.